# CSS div border with offset

Tags: css, border

How can I make a div's side (left/right) border start lower than it's actual size? I know I can reduce it's height and then add a margin-top, but I don't want that. Is it possible to simply lower down the starting point of the border?

```
__________

|
|
|
```

Comment: link no longer works

Comment: A bit of ASCII art works just as well :) Thanks for notifying me, Mark!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only do this by omitting the top border and either

- adding a top margin to the bottom element or
- adding a bottom margin to the top element

Comment: The top border is not part of the div that I am trying to "lower". It's from a top div. Does that change the situation?

Comment: @AdrianMar: The idea is that the margin separates the bottom div (with the side borders) from the top div (with the horizontal border). Margins are located outside the borders, so you'd have to use margins to separate the divs.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, but that affects the text's position from the div, also lowering it, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @AdrianMar: Is there padding in your bottom div, or is the text flush against its top edge?

Comment: @BoltClock: The text just follows the div, down with the 5px added. But if I add a negative padding to the div, I think it will sort it out. I'll have a go. Thanks for the inspiration:).

Comment: @AdrianMar: No problem, chopping off the padding often works :)